# Electromagnetic waves through perfect diamagnetic (superconductor)

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity

Electromagnetic waves move through the space by varying electric and magnetic fields in the space.

My question is that how can they cross a material through which which there is no magnetic field. I am talking about superconductor.

As it is known by meisseiner effect that superconductor is a perfect diamagnetic

Then if a wave approaches a superconductor electric field would pass but magnetic field cannot hence no em wave through superconductor and hence beyond it

Comment: The waves cannot pass through.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissner_effect. The first illustration is of the magnetic fields being deflected, that is, not passing through.

Answer (score 1):

You answered your own question. Electromagnetic waves get reflected by conductors. This is because as it approaches, the waves induces fluctuations in the conductor. By the time the waves gets to the conductor, the interference between the two result in a wave going in the opposite direction.